# How to get city's uniqe id from Accuweather api?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get weather forecast from specific city, i've followed the [API](https://developer.accuweather.com/accuweather-forecast-api/apis/get/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/%7BlocationKey%7D) instructions but couldn't figure out how get the city's id.

Here is the api request:

```
http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/215854
```

From where should i get the last number (215854) ?

Comment: https://developer.accuweather.com/accuweather-locations-api/apis look at city search. The Location API gives you the city id to use with the Forecasts API.

Comment: !Thanks! that's what i was looking

Comment: You can it from https://developer.accuweather.com/accuweather-locations-api/apis/get/locations/v1/regions

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from 
https://developer.accuweather.com/accuweather-locations-api/apis/get/locations/v1/regions

It will give you the below response
[image]